# Even and Odd func

Tags: python, numbers

For an assignment, I'm supposed to create a code that asks the user to input a number and tells them if it's even or odd but if the user puts in a letter or word, the code is supposed to keep asking for a number until they put one in. The code I have so far is...

```
import math


def even_odd(num):
    if num%2 == 0:
    return "even"
else:
    return"odd"

num = number
while num == None:
    try:
        number = int(input("Enter the number:"))
        successful = True
    except:
        print("This is an invalid answer, please 
        enter a number")
```

ans = even_odd(num)
print(ans)

Comment: You don't update `num` inside your loop, so the condition `num == None` is never altered. Also your indentation is all over the place: this code would error as soon as you tried to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually very close, so I don't feel too bad about helping you out.

```
import math

def even_odd(num):
    if num%2 == 0:
        return "even"
    else:
        return"odd"

num = None
while num == None:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter the number:"))
    except:
        print("This is an invalid answer, please enter a number")

ans = even_odd(num)
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

The input type is **`str`**, so you should cast it to the **`int`**.

```py
def do():
    try:
        ans = int(input())
    except Exception:
        do()
    else:
        res = "even" if ans % 2 == 0 else "odd"
        print(res)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do()
```

**Output:**

```
sdsd
sds
23
odd
```